# Get object and the modifier data_path using python

Tags: python

I have a modifier object

```
<bpy_struct, SubsurfModifier("Subdivision") at 0x0000021FF0A3AF28>
```

and i was wondering how can i extract the full data_path from that modifier object without the need of using a loop on the scene to find the corresponding object

so from there i want to have this

```
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere'].modifiers["Subdivision"]
```

and this too

```
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']
```

which is the name of the object that has that modifier applied to it

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can usually get a handle on an object's holder with [bpy_struct.id_data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=id_data#bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_data).

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
mod = obj.modifiers["Array"]
print(mod.id_data)
```

> <bpy_struct, Object("Cube") at 0x000001E51A4D4808>

You can get the data path with [bpy_struct.path_from_id](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=path_resolve#bpy.types.bpy_struct.path_from_id).

`print(mod.path_from_id())`

> modifiers["Array"]

```
object_path = repr(mod.id_data)
print(object_path)
full_path = f"{object_path}.{mod.path_from_id()}"
print(full_path)
```

> bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

> bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["Array"]

Comment: also `repr(mod.id_data)`

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ooh nice thank you for that !